# Cómo dar formato a los números de un datatable

Tags: javascript, php, html

Me gustaría dar formato a una tabla en JavaScript. Tengo 1 tabla con datos que son los siguientes T.UNIT: valor que me muestra en la tabla es 125.000 quisiera volverlo a 125. Luego de eso tengo el CUNIT: .055555 Lo que quiero: 0.056 En mi base de datos mi procedure me da un resultado 125.000 y el otro 0.055555.

```js
var tbl_ctsunitario;
function Listar_CTSUnitario(id){
    tbl_ctsunitario = $("#tabla_ctsunitario").DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "searching": {"regex":false},
        "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100,-1],[10,25,50,100, "All"]],
        "pageLength":10,
        "destroy": true,
        "async": false,
        "processing": true,
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo":false,
        "sDom":'t',
        "ajax":{
            "url": "../controller/datos/controlador_listar_ctsunitario.php",
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                id:id
            }
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"PRODUCTO"},
            {"data":"T_UNIT"},
            {"data":"CUNIT"},
        ],
        "language":idioma_espanol,
        select: true
    });
}
```

```html
<table id="tabla_ctsunitario" class="display">
<thead>
<label>Costos Unitario</label>
<tr>
<th>PROD</th>
<th style="width:100px">T.UNIT</th>
<th style="width:100px">CUNIT</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la funcion `toFixed()` como se ve en el ejemplo:

```js
const log = document.querySelector('#log');
const number1 = 125.000;
const number2 = 0.055555;

log.innerHTML = `
    <p>Number1 = ${number1} => ${number1.toFixed(0)}</p>
    <p>Number2 = ${number2} => ${number2.toFixed(3)}</p>`;
```

```html
<main id="log"></main>
```

Comment: Como podría ponerlo en el js xfa

Answer (score 0):

También puedes hacerlo desde SQL...

En `MySql` con la función `ROUND(numero, cantidadDecimales)` puedes retornar el resultado sin decimales o con la cantidad de decimales que le indiques.

```
SELECT ROUND(125.000, 0);
//Resultado 125
SELECT ROUND(0.055555, 3);
//Resultado 0.056
```

En `SQL Server` puedes usar la función `CAST(numero AS tipo(longitud, cantidadDecimales)) AS alias`

```
SELECT CAST(125.000 AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS NUM;
//Resultado 125
SELECT CAST(0.0555 AS NUMERIC(10,3)) AS NUM;
//Resultado .056
```

Comment: estoy buscando algo que sea en javascript, pero se aprecia la ayuda